perform a general search in a mongoengine document to find instance of a particular value
I have a created a database in mongodb and setup mongoengine in python to interface with it. The next step is to setup a query which will go through the documents and search for specific values. I have a basic setup but was hoping for something a bit more dynamic
from mongoengine import Document, EmbeddedDocument, StringField, IntField, EmbeddedDocumentField, MapField, Q
   
class games(EmbeddedDocument):
    game_name = StringField()

class PlayersDocument(Document):
    name = StringField()
    games = MapField(EmbeddedDocumentField(games), db_field="console")


def search_document(console, game_name)
    query = Q(**{f'games__{console}__game_name': game_name})
    PlayersDocument.objects(query)

I was hoping to convert this into a general setup where it would look through the embedded docuements without having to specify. However many of my attempts do not work.
def search_document(game_name)
    query = Q(**{'games__{}__game_name': game_name})
    PlayersDocument.objects(query)

def search_document(game_name)
    query = Q(**{'games__$in__game_name': game_name})
    PlayersDocument.objects(query)

